# How to deploy smart contract on zkSync Era Testnet using Remix and MetaMask

Tags: remix, metamask, zksync

I want to use the zkSync Era Testnet to do some testing with different smart contracts. I am using Remix with MetaMask as the injected provider to deploy the contract on the testnet. The contract compiles just fine, and I have been able to use this method to deploy the exact same contracts on the Polygon zkEVM Testnet. However, when I have the zkSync Era Testnet selected in MetaMask and try to deploy the contract, I get the following error message  (see picture):

> Gas estimation failed. Failed to serialize transaction:
> toAddressIsNull","id":4712902792361366

[image: Failed to serialize transaction: toAddressIsNull","id":4712902792361366]

This is the smart contract I'm trying to deploy:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

contract Dummy {
    address public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

Although, ultimately I would ofcourse deploy different smart contracts, but even this dummy contract won't deploy.
I have the zkSync Era Testnet configured in MetaMask with this RPC URL (see picture):

> https://testnet.era.zksync.dev

[image: zkSyncTestnetConfig]

The configuration works fine on MetaMask, and I have some ETH on this network. I have also tried to change the RPC URL to these other ones which I found online, but that didn't change the error:

> https://zksync2-testnet.zksync.dev

> https://zksync-era-testnet.rpc.thirdweb.com

It is only the zkSync Era Testnet that I have encountered so far which gives these errors, I have been able to deploy smart contracts on other testnets just fine. Any help or suggestions as to what I could try / change would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried forcing the transaction? Unfortunately, zkSync is EVM compatible, not equivalent, ([more on this distinction here](https://vitalik.ca/general/2022/08/04/zkevm.html)) so you need our specific compiler to compile your contract. See here:

https://era.zksync.io/docs/dev/building-on-zksync/hello-world.html

You’ll need to be familiar with Hardhat, but the tutorial walks you through in a step by step fashion.

Comment: Forcing the transaction unfortunately resulted in it failing. I had no idea that EVM compatibility would affect simple smart contracts even at this level. I'll use Hardhat with the specific zkSync compiler instead!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use hardhat-zksync-solc.

This is what the documentation says:
To deploy a contract on Ethereum, a user sends a transaction to the zero address (0x000...000) with the data field of the transaction equal to the contract bytecode concatenated with the constructor parameters.

To deploy a contract on zkSync Era, a user calls the create function of the ContractDeployer system contract providing the hash of the contract to be published, as well as the constructor arguments. (Format: https://era.zksync.io/docs/dev/building-on-zksync/contracts/contract-deployment.html#format-of-bytecode-hash)

The documentation recommends **Hardhat** to deploy as it requires a different compiler https://era.zksync.io/docs/tools/hardhat/

Deploying contracts on zkSync Era is also possible via L1-L2 communication. https://era.zksync.io/docs/dev/developer-guides/bridging/l1-l2-interop.html

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [atlaszk online IDE](https://app.atlaszk.com/ide)  to run your deployment on zkSync instead of remix.